# creating a form that returns a price quote based on dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, forms

I am a novice with CSS and HTML I have no experience in anything else. I have created the following site with the following form: http://www.moreformymac.com/get-quote.html

I did not create the code for the form, it was done by someone else using JS.  Is JS the best way to do something like this or is there something better? If my goal is to know how to create this kind of form, and expand it to other products what do I need to start learning first?

Comment: simply said what do you exactly want to do with your form?

Comment: I want a user to be able to enter various parameters about a device (year, screen size, processor condition etc.) have different price values linked to those parameters that will generate a price quote. have those parameters displayed to the user with a final price quote. gather contact information from the user.  once all of that information is gathered I want all of that information e-mailed to me. and I want this system to be expandable to many different devices (it is currently just for calculating a price for 2 specific devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial to start with treating formular values, in php http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp